# Work grouping/chaining for WorkManager similar to android-priority-jobqueue

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-priority-jobqueue

We are migrating to [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), the successor of [android-priority-jobqueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue) library. How can we implement work [grouping](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue/wiki/Job-Configuration) with WorkManager. We could achieve similar structure by using [WorkContinuation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkContinuation) but it required a reference to [WorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkRequest) instead of synchronizing on the same string.

How can we implement work grouping/chaining using WorkManager?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that we can achieve this by using [WorkManager.beginUniqueWork()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#beginUniqueWork%28java.lang.String,%20androidx.work.ExistingWorkPolicy,%20androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequest...%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this sample provided by Google. It contains a chain of image processing. All related `Worker` is working under `ImageOperations.java` as a chain of work.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/WorkManagerSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/background/ImageOperations.kt